# Insert cyrillic symbols into MySQL fails

Tags: mysql, jpa, cyrillic

Hy guys, i am developing some SpringBoot MVC aplication. Using Angular on frontend, Hibernate JPA on backend. I need to insert cyrillic symbols into DB, but only i get is '????'.

In application.properties i have this config:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://adressToDB/NameOfDB

spring.jpa.properties.connection.CharSet=utf8
spring.jpa.properties.connection.characterEncoding=utf8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
```

I tried to insert directly cyrillic symbols into DB, but insert statement fails with this error :

```
INSERT INTO `matica`.`user` (`email`, `name`, `user_id`) VALUES ('стева', 'стева', '57');

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1366: 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xD1\x81\xD1\x82\xD0\xB5...' for column 'email' at row 1
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `matica`.`user` (`email`, `name`, `user_id`) VALUES ('стева', 'стева', '57')
```

Comment: What is the encoding for your database and table?

Comment: This is settings for database: http://prntscr.com/ab2hwn,

Comment: In PHP you would use 'SET NAMES UTF8', after connection to mysql is established. make your tables utf8 and field names too, you could use ut8_general_ci (case insensitive)

Comment: I did it, but it wont work. Same error persists.